# PHP: Get day name of calender list

Tags: php, date, calendar

I'm using this script:

```
$monate = array("Januar","Februar","März","April","Mai","Juni",
                "Juli","August","September","Oktober","November","Dezember");

echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2>";
echo "<tr>";
for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++) {
    $tage = date("t",mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 1, date("Y")));
    echo "<th colspan=".$tage.">".$monate[$x-1]."</th>";
}

echo "</tr><tr>";

for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++) {
    $tage = date("t",mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 1, date("Y")));

    for($monatstage=1;$monatstage<=$tage;$monatstage++) {
        echo "<td>".$monatstage."</td>"; // day of name wanted!
    }
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Now i would like to display also the day of the name behind the number of the day. Is this in some way possible with the date("w")-function?

Also it would be nice to use this script with given year and not just with the actual year.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: So did you bother trying something for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have generated a date using date() already it is just a case of doing the same again but using the day `$monatstage` in a similiar way but with a different date formating parameter

```
for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++) {
    $tage = date("t",mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 1, date("Y")));

    for($monatstage=1; $monatstage<=$tage; $monatstage++) {
        echo "<td>".$monatstage. date(" l",mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, $monatstage, date("Y"))) . "</td>".PHP_EOL; // day of name wanted!
    }
}
```

RESULT:

```
<td>1 Sunday</td>
<td>2 Monday</td>
<td>3 Tuesday</td>
<td>4 Wednesday</td>
<td>5 Thursday</td>
<td>6 Friday</td>
<td>7 Saturday</td>
<td>8 Sunday</td>
<td>9 Monday</td>
<td>10 Tuesday</td>

etc etc
```